# snappypdf error while creating a pdf in laravel

Tags: laravel, knp-snappy

The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback QSslSock

this is the line where it is occuring

```
   $pdf = SnappyPDF::loadHTML($html)->save('reports/cargo_manifest_' . str_pad($cargo->id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.pdf');
```

The code works fine in my local environment but it gives the above mentioned error on my server,

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check whether your view/html page error is related to missing assets such as images, fonts, css, js or incorrect tag, as stated in this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/222#issuecomment-806325190).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing a dependency.

Try this: `sudo apt install libssl-dev` or `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`

If it doesn't work, tell me what is your server operating system and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: my server is linux, could you tell me what is this command for ?

Comment: Linux is approx. 99% of the servers :p To help you, we need to know the distribution (debian? ubuntu? centos?) Did you try the commands in my answer? What was the output?